# How to filter out hidden files and directories in 'find'?

Tags: command-line, find, hidden-files

I would like to list all the non-hidden files and directories in my path.

This means that files beginning with `.` should be excluded from the result, along with files whose path contains a hidden directory:

```
foo/bar/.bazz.rc # Exclude
foo/.bar/bazz.rc # Exclude
```

How do I do that? I've tried:

```
find -maxdepth 2 -not -iname "*/.*"
```

But I still have hidden files in my results.

Answer (score 3):

Use `path` instead of `iname`:

```
find -not -path '*/.*'
```

- `*` - matches any string.
- `/` - directory separator.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the opposite and match them. It allows `find` to prune, which prevents descending into the matching directories it can speed up your search considerably.

```
find -path '*/.*' -prune -o -print
```

Explicit use of `-print` on the right side only prints the non-matching objects, in this case, visible files and folders.